# What is the significance of the dot in bash commands and how is it different from an asterisk?

Tags: shell, directory, filenames, wildcards

I'm trying to understand the significance of the dot in bash and how it differs from an asterisk.  Can someone please elaborate?  For example, what's the difference between `cp -ar /foo/. /foo2/` and `cp -pr /foo/* /foo2/`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The dot (`.`) is just the `.` directory inside a directory which is the same as the directory itself (`ls -la /foo` will show it to you). So if you copy `foo/.` elsewhere, you effectively copy all the tree below `foo` without copying `foo` itself (you're copying it into `foo2/.` which is the same as `foo2`).

`/foo/*` is expanded by the shell to the list of non-hidden files and directories in `/foo`, so it would copy the same directory structure under `/foo` into `/foo2` as well, except for the dotfiles/dotdirs. Effectively, `cp` will receive (potentially) many arguments. If the list is too big, it may even cause the execution of `cp` to fail.

Comment: Sorry but I'm getting confused. So by nature, the asterisk makes the command recursive? In other words `cp -r /foo/*` does the same thing as `cp /foo/*`  ?

Comment: @MikeB, no, the shell only expands the list of files in the /foo directory. It doesn't alter the behavior of cp. Use `set -x` or `echo cp -pr /foo/* /foo2` to see what's going on. It's important to realise that it's the shell that expands the wildcards. `cp` doesn't see the star.

Comment: What about this? chmod 755 -R . versus chmod 755 -R *