# shell: Different path patterns

Tags: shell, cp

What is the difference among following path patterns in Linux

- `./` e.g. `cp ./ [destination-path]`
- `./.` e.g. `cp ./. [destination-path]`
- `./*` e.g. `cp ./* [destination-path]`
- `./**` e.g. `cp ./** [destination-path]`

Comment: Did you try them? What happened? Is anything else still unclear?

Comment: This question combines https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62070/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381282/ , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62660/ .

Comment: @JeffSchaller I have provided `cp` as an example to make my question clear. I want to know the main difference.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes I have executed them, found ./. and ./ same, ./* copies non hidden files but couldn't find the difference of ./**.

Comment: Thank you very much @JdeBP for useful links, I found the answer from your given links. LOL where were they when I was searching, I was not using proper keywords perhaps.

Comment: The `*` and `**` will get expanded my the shell. See `glob`ing  in the manual for your shell. To understand `./.` first understand `././././././././.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two would make more sense with a recursive copy, i.e. `cp -r`. The difference comes up if the source is a named directory, and the destination exists. Of these:

```
cp -r src/  dest
cp -r src/. dest
```

the first would copy `src` into `dest`, creating `dest/src` and files within it (`src/a` becomes `dest/src/a`), while the latter copies the contents of `src`, so `src/a` becomes `dest/a`.

In the other two, the shell expands the glob, so the contents of the directory (except dotfiles) are copied even without `-r`.

```
cp ./*  dest
cp ./** dest
```

In the first, the shell  expands `./*` to the list of filenames in the current directory (except those starting with a dot), and `cp` copies them. In the second, shells supporting it would expand `./**` to a recursive listing of filenames, and again `cp` would copy the files it was listed.

The recursive `**` works at least in Bash if `shopt -s globstar` is set, in ksh with `set -o globstar`.

Neither Bash or ksh includes files or directories with names starting with dot in the result of `**`, regardless of which level in the tree they appear, so using that is not a very good way to make a complete copy of a full directory structure; `cp -r . dest` would copy dotfiles too.

Bash has `shopt -s dotglob` which unhides dotfiles with both `*` and `**`, I'm not sure if ksh has a similar feature.

Comment: Thank you for such a good explanation, you said that "except those starting with a dot" mean hidden files will not be included in the list, what if I want to include them in the list or what if the source has many dot files, they will not be copied?

Comment: @Adnan, yeah, `cp ./** dest/` would miss all dotfiles, unless you use `shopt -s dotglob` in Bash. So it's probably easier to just use `cp -r` for recursive copies (or `cp -a` in GNU cp).